# Extra space above anchor tag?

Tags: html, css

Here is my HTML:

```
<a id="rightArrow">&Rarr;</a>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
#rightArrow {
  transition: color .3s ease-in-out;
  font-size: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#rightArrow:hover {
  color: #01c6ae;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Even though I have padding and margin set to 0, there is still a lot of extra space above the arrow and a little below it. I only want the arrow to change color if the cursor is over it, not if it is above or below it. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pnsnh8av/

Comment: The jsfiddle is empty?

Comment: use `line-height` to remove the extra space.

Comment: The font size is 100px, so that's the height of the character cell. Not much you can do about that. Changing the `line-height` or giving the element negative margins will change the space it occupies on screen, but not the area where the hovering occurs. The only solution I see is to create an img with the arrow.

Comment: @MrLister Thanks for explaining it. I guess I'll have to find another way to do what I wanted, thanks for the tip.

Comment: There is a solution though, using `inline-block` and `overflow`; see @Siguza's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the `↠` character just has a lot of space above and below it.
You get similar results with `_`, for example.

I've come up with three solutions so far:

## 1. `clip-path`

You can use `clip-path` to "remove" the blank areas of your tag, but Firefox and IE do not currently support `clip-path` with shapes.

```
display: inline-block;
-webkit-clip-path: inset(47% 0% 25% 0%);
clip-path: inset(47% 0% 25% 0%);
```

`47% 0% 25% 0%` (read: remove 47% from top and 25% from bottom) is the approximate area that is blank in the the `↠` character.
This has the advantage of not breaking when you decide to change the font size, but it won't work in all browsers (yet). [[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pnsnh8av/24/)]
(If positioning relative to the line matters, you should be able to use `position: relative` and `top` or `bottom` to get the desired alignment.)

## 2. Fixed size + `overflow`

A cross-browser solution is to make it an `inline-block`, set `overflow: hidden` and fiddle with `line-height` and `height`. I found these values work pretty well, but they're basically random:

```
display: inline-block;
overflow: hidden;
line-height: 20px;
height: 32px;
```

Should work in all browsers, but you have to fiddle with the values again if you change the font size. [[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pnsnh8av/27/)]

## 3. Images

I originally wanted to suggest using images instead of text, but realised it wouldn't be that trivial if you want the color to be animated.
But it is actually still quite simple, you just have an outer element with a background image (cyan arrow), containing an `img` tag (black arrow), on which the opacity is animated from 1 to 0 on hover.
This works cross-browser too and has the advantage of correctly showing up even in browsers/on machines that do not support that character, but of course you have to create two new images every time you want to change anything. [[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pnsnh8av/30/)]
(In production, you should probably not inline images though.)

Comment: Ah. I was just about to post roughly the same solution. One improvement would be to set the line-height to `.32` instead of `20px`, then it will be relative to the font size and won't have to change when the font size changes. And you won't need `height`.

Comment: Mhh... kind of works too, but it either cuts a few pixels from the bottom of the character or has a few empty pixels above it where `:hover` can be toggled already...

Comment: Oh, you're right, I see that different fonts have the arrows in different vertical positions relative to the baseline. I just happened to be testing with a font where my solution looked good. Oh well. Maybe the OP should use an img after all. Or a webfont.

Comment: I wanted to suggest an image first, but try making an image fade to a different color in CSS...

Comment: Gonna try that now :P

Answer (score 1):

`padding` and `margin` won't have the expected effect on the `a` element (which is inline by default), so you have to set `display` to `inline-block`
Second, the character itself is quite high, so to reduce element's height keeping the font-size you would set `line-height` to something less, like for example 50%:

```
line-height: 50%;
display: inline-block;
```

see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pnsnh8av/21/

Comment: But it still won't work I already tried that.. From Bottom it still won't work. check your solution. http://jsfiddle.net/pnsnh8av/22/

Comment: The OP's concern is with the size of the hovering area (the location on the screen where the arrow changes colour), not the space it takes up as such.

Comment: This still seems to leave a lot of space at the bottom.

Comment: its beacuse of the font size of that arrow by default css will increase the size of the image along with crea and circumferance instread of this u can use font awesome or use custom image